# @DataJpaTest scanning entity of external jar

Tags: spring, testing, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have a multiple module project

```
root 
+-- common
+-- webProject
```

And, I have tried to test on `webProject`

```
@RunWith(SPringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest 
@SpringBootTest(classes = {XxxService.class})
public class XxxServiceTest { 
    @Autowired
    XxxService xxxService;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        xxxService.method();
        ...
    }
}
```

`XxxServiceTest` is located in `webProject` but, `XxxService`, `XxxRepository` are located in `common` module.

So, It couldn't get beans of `entity`, `repository`

In conclusion, How can I get entity and repository of external jar?

Answer (score 0):

Set the packagesToScan property on your session factory to the package(s) your entities are in.